# Ubuntu 12.10 not rebooting after hard shutdown. Cannot access BIOS

Tags: 12.10, shutdown, suspend, reboot

Ubuntu 12.10 not rebooting after hard shutdown.
After I suspended my laptop, I tried to wake it up but it did not, when I pressed any of its keys. So I did a forced shutdown. Now I am not able to reboot it after pressing the power button.
Only the numlock and capslock lights blink. 
Not able to access BIOS also.
Tried to boot through LiveCD, but I think it is not at the top of the Boot device order.
Also, my laptop heats up normally. When I remove/insert DVD in the DVD-drive, it makes a normal sound after inserting the CD, which means system is working. But there is no display on the screen.
Please help.

System Details: hp pavilion dv6 2005ax
AMD Processor, ATI RADEON graphics card, 4gb RAM (link below for complete specifications)
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01869762&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=4039727

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a hardware problem to me.  Check this out: [HP forums](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Display-and-Video-e-g-Windows-8/Blank-screen-with-4-num-lock-and-caps-lock-blinking/td-p/130674)